# Tell taxonomy links to use route in custom module

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, routes

I have a module where I created a route `/page/tag/{term}` that uses a controller for modifications to how the term page is handled.

The problem is that when any page displays these term links, they don't use the custom route, but the default `/taxonomy/term/{id}`.

How can I tell the taxonomy term links to use my custom route?

Adding the path as the term alias skips over the custom route entirely.

OR, how would I get rid of the custom route and create a pathauto pattern using the same path, but tell those pages to use my custom controller?

I have tried both methods without success...

---

Here is what I've tried with modifying the existing route:

modulename.services.yml

```
services:
  modulename.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\modulename\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber, priority: 100 }
```

modulename/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php

```
namespace Drupal\modulename\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
        if ($route = $collection->get('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical')) {
            // i've tried both of these
            $route->addDefaults(['_controller' => '\Drupal\modulename\Controller\ListController::list_by_tag' ']);
            $route->addDefaults(['_title' => 'test']);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Edit: after seeing this, I thought about keeping my custom route and using the alterRoutes to change the links...

`$route->setPath('/page/tag');`

That worked, but it adds on ?taxonomy_term=123

How can I get the term name into the url? `/page/tag/term`

---

Update:

Still can't figure out how to get the term name from the route (without loading the taxonomy entity - I'd imagine that is too much load)

Also, I will need to make sure I'm in a specific vocabulary before changing the route.

Any ideas?

Comment: you do not get rid of the original route, get rid of your route and alter the existing route instead. routes are hardcoded like links were in <=d7 so altering them makes no sense.

Comment: How would I go about doing this and having the existing route use my custom controller?

Comment: Create event subscriber service from \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface and listen to \Drupal\Core\Routing\RoutingEvents::ALTER event.

Comment: ´RouteSubscriberBase` already contains this even listener. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm also using a `RouteSubscriber` to change the default controller responsible for handling taxonomy term entities. I also wanted to use a custom template only for a specific taxonomy (called `my_taxonomy` in the example below).

Here is the code for the `RouteSubscriber`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RoutingEvents;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
        if ($route = $collection->get('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical')) {
            $route->setDefaults([
                '_controller' => '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\DefaultController::listAll',
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        $events[RoutingEvents::ALTER] = ['onAlterRoutes', -200];
        return $events;
    }

}
```

And here is the code for the controller. Note that a custom render array can be returned only for terms of the specific taxonomy `my_taxonomy`. All other terms fall back to the default controller used by the `views` module in the original route:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\views\Routing\ViewPageController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends ControllerBase {

    public function listAll(Request $request) {
        $render = [];

        $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term');
        $term = Term::load($tid);
        $bundle = $term->bundle();
        if ($bundle == 'my_taxonomy') {
            // render array for your custom template
        } else {
            // falls back to the default ViewPageController to handle all other taxonomies
            $viewPageController = new ViewPageController();
            $render = $viewPageController->handle('taxonomy_term', 'page_1', \Drupal::routeMatch());
        }

        // Return render array
        return $render;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is almost functional. In order for term-pages from other vocabularies to work RouteSubscriber needs one small addition:

`$route->setDefaults([
  '_controller' => '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\DefaultController::listAll',
  'view_id' => 'taxonomy_term'
]);`

The view_id default needs to be added so other vocabularies can load the proper view.